# XQuery: show max value along with other information

Tags: xquery

Let's say I have a XML file containing product elements with the following structure:

```
<product>
  <name></name>
  <price></price>
</product>
```

I need a query to obtain the most expensive product. The following XQuery works fine:

```
max(
   for $product in collection('/Products')//product
      return ($product/prize)
)
```

But I would like to get the name of the most expensive product as well.
I can't figure out how to achieve this with a simple flwor query using the max() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the max value preflight, and use a predicate to return products matching it:

```
let $products := collection('/Products')//product
let $max := max($products/prize)
return $products[prize = $max]
```